# 'Label does not contain a definition for text'

Tags: c#, xaml

I dont know why I'm unable to assign text to a label, if I'm using a textbox then it does it fine...

my xaml:

```
<Label Name="TimerLabel"  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="1" />
```

xaml.cs:

```
TimerLabel.Text = "sadssa";
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpjY1.jpg

I have the right references I believe... I'm able to assign text to the label fine directly from the .xaml using Content="texthere" but I cant seem to assign text via the code. (Tried TimerLabel.Content = "asds"; but no result https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7UyU.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried setting the *Content* ?

Comment: `TimerLabel.Content`.

Comment: Yeah TimerLabel.Content="asds" was the first thing I tried http://imgur.com/a/COPPu

Answer (score 3):

Assign the `Content` property of the label. Or use `TextBlock` instead.

`TextBlock` is roughly the same as a `Label` from WinForms.

As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock(VS.95).aspx):

> The TextBlock control is the primary
>   element for displaying text in
>   Silverlight based applications.
>
> Provides a lightweight control for
>   displaying small amounts of text...

You might want to consider a TextBlock depending on how your using it.  Again per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.label(VS.95).aspx):

> A Label control displays a caption,
>   required field indicator, and
>   validation error indicator to the
>   user. It is typically used together
>   with an input control, such as a
>   TextBox. If you do not need to display
>   required field or validation
>   indicators, you can use the TextBlock
>   control instead.

Answer (score 0):

Label able to contain not only text, so use `Content` property instead.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you have the incorrect dll referenced at the top of your .cs file. For example I had incorrectly referenced:

*using System.Reflection.Emit;*

When really I needed

**using System.Web.UI.WebControls;**

Answer (score 0):

In my situation I'm using nop commerce so the `@Html.LabelFor()` needed to be replaced with `@html.NopLabelFor()`

I also had to add the following reference `@using Nop.Web.Framework`